# JQuery Remove Element When Parent Position Changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

I am making a website with a sticky navbar and would a symbol to appear when the navbar reaches the very top of the page (user scrolls down) and disappear when the navbar leaves the top of the page (the user scrolls up). So far I can make the symbol appear but not reappear.

Below is the js code and the HTML for the nav:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var distance = $('#navbar').offset().top,
    $window = $(window);


  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() < distance) {
      $("#nav").remove(
        "<li id=\"navSymbol\"><a href=\"#\">▲</a></li>");

    }

    if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance) {
      if ($("#navSymbol").length) {
        console.log("not adding")

      } else {
        $("#nav").prepend(
          "<li id=\"navSymbol\"><a href=\"#\">▲</a></li>");
      }
    }


  });

});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div style="height: 25vw;"></div>

<div class="sticky-top" id="navbar" style="padding-top: 3vw; padding-bottom: 3vw; background-color: white;">
  <ul class="nav justify-content-center sticky-top" id="navcontent">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="nav" href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="nav" href="#">Staffing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="nav" href="#">Marketing and Finance</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="nav" href="#">Future Prospects</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div style="height: 100vw;"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Do you have issues for the node appearing the second time, or is just the node not disapearing ?

Comment: It just doesn't disappear, no issues with appearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the [remove](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) method, you are not removing your node right now.

- The remove method without argument is removing the current node.
- The remove method with argument is removing the element from the provided selector.

By providing the HTML, you will generate a selector for a node not attached to the DOM document. Removing it is then having no impact as he's not there.

You can try something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var distance = $('#navbar').offset().top,
        $window = $(window);

    $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() < distance) {
        $("#navSymbol").remove();
    }

    if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance) {
        if ($("#navSymbol").length) {
            console.log("not adding")
        } else {
            $("#nav").prepend("<li id=\"navSymbol\"><a href=\"#\">▲</a></li>");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just hide your element with jQuery hide function. And show it again with the show function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var previous_distance = 0;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var distance = $('#navbar').offset().top;
    if (previous_distance < distance) {
      $("#navSymbol").hide();
    }
    else {
      $("#navSymbol").show();
    }
    previous_distance = distance
  });

});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div style="height: 25vw;"></div>

<div class="sticky-top" id="navbar" style="padding-top: 3vw; padding-bottom: 3vw; background-color: white;">
  <ul class="nav justify-content-center sticky-top" id="navcontent">
    <li id="navSymbol"><a href=\"#\">▲</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="nav" href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="nav" href="#">Staffing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="nav" href="#">Marketing and Finance</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="nav" href="#">Future Prospects</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div style="height: 100vw;"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code 'remove' method removes nodes contained in the jQuery collection that initiated the call At the time 'remove()' is called.

You could use

```
 $("#nav").text("About");
```

instead of

```
$("#nav").remove(
    "<li id=\"navSymbol\"><a href=\"#\">▲</a></li>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var distance = $('#navbar').offset().top,
$window = $(window);


$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($window.scrollTop() < distance) {
  $("#navSymbol").remove();


}

if ($window.scrollTop() >= distance) {
  if ($("#navSymbol").length) {
    console.log("not adding")

  } else {
    $("#nav").prepend(
      "<li id=\"navSymbol\" ><a href=\"#\">▲</a></li>");
  }
}


});

});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div style="height: 25vw;"></div>

<div class="sticky-top" id="navbar" style="padding-top: 3vw; padding-bottom: 3vw; background-color: white;">
  <ul class="nav justify-content-center sticky-top" id="navcontent">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="nav" href="#about">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="nav" href="#">Staffing</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="nav" href="#">Marketing and Finance</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="nav" href="#">Future Prospects</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div style="height: 100vw;"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Please use the remove() function to remove any element because jquery give function to remove the specific element.